# How can I get all elements of the selected form

Tags: jquery

Hello Let's say I have two forms on a page.

Now I want to get all input elements (even if they are hidden).

The code I have now looks like this:

```
    $("form.prev, form.next").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      var inputs = $(this).filter(':input');
      console.log(inputs);
      var values = {};

      inputs.each(function() {
        values[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });

    console.log(values);
});
```

I am expecting to see a list of the input elements with their keys and values. But the result of `console.log(values);` is an empty object

What is going wrong over here?

Comment: `inputs.each(function(index, obj) {...` and then `values[obj.attr('name')] = $(obj).val();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to do this yourself - the `serialize()` function was invented for this purpose.

```
$("form.prev, form.next").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = $(this).serialize();
    // data is a key/value string, you can now use it in AJAX requests for example
});
```

[jQuery API - Serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :use `.find()` instead of `.filter()`

```
$("form.prev, form.next").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      var inputs = $(this).find(':input');
      console.log(inputs);
      var values = {};

      inputs.each(function() {
        values[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });

    console.log(values);
});
```